# No Such User Here sending an email from subdomain to main domain

Tags: email, subdomain, cpanel, cloudflare, mx-record

We have the following scenario:

- maindomain.com registered at cloudflare.com
- maindomain.com is ponted to srvA.datacenter.com
- A record: subdomain created in cloudflare.com and pointed to main IP in new srvB.anotherdatacenter.com with WHM/cPanel
- In srvB.anotherdatacenter.com we have created the maindomain.com and then a subdomain like this subdomain.maindomain.com
- Now if you enter to subdomain.maindomain.com works fine, the problem is when you send an email from user@maindomain.com to anotheruser@subdomain.maindomain.com, it returns the following error:

  ---

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

user@maindomain.com
    No Such User Here

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: 
Received: from cpaneluser by ip-69-161-24-111.ip.secureserver.net with local (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from )
    id 1XKWDo-0001KJ-Sf; Thu, 21 Aug 2014 10:32:24 -0700
To: =?utf-8?B?RWRnYXI=?= 
Subject: =?utf-8?B?R3J1cG8gTWFjbERTYsbGdRTYZWdhIGY63xfVuY2lhcyBkdSBvcmRRTbiADsdE5==?=
From: Another User on Subdomain 
Date: Thu, 21 Aug 2014 12:32:24 -0500
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id:

---

- If you send an email to gmail or hotmail or exmple.com it works fine

What's wrong in my configuration? maybe is missing another configuration?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to ask your mail provider about this, unfortunately. It sounds like you may be missing something to mail and MX records, or something isn't configured properly in your mail set up.